# Should "tags thrown in for publicity" be removed?

Tags: discussion, support, tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should I remove tags which don't seem appropriate?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19714/should-i-remove-tags-which-dont-seem-appropriate)
>   [When are question tags irrelevant and should be removed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97182/when-are-question-tags-irrelevant-and-should-be-removed)

Consider this question:

[What are reasonable underlying implementations of virtual or dynamic dispatch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8252485/what-are-reasonable-underlying-implementations-of-virtual-or-dynamic-dispatch)

The user added tags C++, Java, and C# to his language neutral question, simply to get followers of those tags to look at his question.

Is this reasonable or should such tags be nuked?

Comment: Of course they should be removed; they don't describe the question. This sort of "publicity stunt" is borderline abusive. I'm pretty sure this has been asked before on MSO, searching now....

Comment: @PopularDemand: Done.

Comment: Meh, too tired to find the exact duplicate, but here are three similar posts with the same general point: [Should I remove tags which don't seem appropriate?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19714/131713), [Should imprecise tags be removed?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/84361/131713) and [When are question tags irrelevant and should be removed?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/97182/131713).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whether or not it is appropriate is a judgment call in some cases, but perhaps the useful question to ask is:

> Would someone following this tag be interested in this question?

If yes, then the tag is fine.

If no, remove it.

Comment: Perhaps we need a tag named 'meta-language' or something that describes the fact you need advice on the best way to do something, but need help deciding which technique. It could even be 'meta-language-C-like' and 'meta-language-script-like'. Perhaps there's something out there like this already.....just a thought.